# Broken Python in Mac M1

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, homebrew, apple-m1

I've messed up some python installations in MacBook Air M1

On my command

```
python
```

This is the message I get

```
zsh: no such file or directory: /usr/local/bin/python3.9.2
```

But when I use

```
python3
```

It works!

How do I make it work with python directly

Comment: What does `type python` show? Also, can you show `ls -lh /usr/local/bin/python*`?

Comment: I'm not sure what this has to do specifically with [tag:apple-m1] - can you elaborate on why you've included this in your title and chosen this tag? Why not just `alias` `python` to `python3`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Run these first:

```
alias python=/usr/local/bin/python3
alias pip=/usr/local/bin/pip3
```

It is annoying though, because macs come with a watered down version of python. I had it all set up before with a package manager and everything, but then the latest mac update wiped out my whole setup, and I even had to reinstall real python. now I jus type python3.

Comment: This didn't work for me, I have an M1 mac, and out of the box it says that python is not recognized.  I installed python with brew, it installed python3, but I still can't run commands that need python.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure your aliases

Type:

```
alias python=python3
```

Or

```
alias python='/usr/local/bin/python3'
```